# React child component css stops working when propery value got updated

Tags: css, reactjs

I am building a web app with ReactJS which lets the user change the background image. I have a main parent component which has the default value for the background image. I have two other child components. 
Component 1: One component which it's background is dynamic.
Component 2: One menu component that the user can choose a different image.

Component 1 CSS:

```
const dynamicStyles = {
      mainContent: {
        background: `url(${this.props.backgroundImage}) no-repeat center center fixed`,
        backgroundSize: "cover"
      }
}
```

When the user changes the background image using the Child 2 component the state of parent component gets updated. Therefore Child 1 component background gets updated.

However the CSS style (backgroundSize: "cover") stops working.How can I just change the image but still keep the CSS applying to this dynamic property?

Comment: Do you have the same aspect ratio on the images?

Comment: @anderssonola Hmm no, there is a list of diff images with diff size which user can choose to set the background. But I want to apply in all cases the size cover. Even when I choose the same default image again to be set CSS is still broken.

Comment: Could you share more of the components code or maybe share a CodeSandbox? I think more info may be required to diagnose the issue.